# retain querystring values when savincustom options in admin

Tags: php, admin, wp-admin, options

Quick question, I have a custom options page which posts to options.php, however I have a few sections to my options page where i change the post url like so: `<form action='options.php?section=sectionname' ..>`

when the options page reloads I need to check which section was just saved i.e. get the sectionname from the querystring, however the options.php page redirects to the options-general.php page and does not retain my query string.

can anyone think of either a way to retain the QS or tell me a better way to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about putting the current section in a hidden form field inside each section, and then when you reload the page, check `$_POST['section']`?

Comment: I've found a way around it in the end as you mentioned using the hidden field and a jquery click to set it then using get_option(...).. as i'm using custom options.